# Maven - Run as - Maven install, возникает ошибка

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

После команды `Maven install` появляется следующая ошибка и ничего не качается:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Project ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Tim\eclipse-workspace\Project\target\Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Project ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Tim\eclipse-workspace\Project\target\Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Tim\.m2\repository\com\tim\project\Project\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Tim\eclipse-workspace\Project\pom.xml to C:\Users\Tim\.m2\repository\com\tim\project\Project\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[    INFO] Total time: 7.259 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-18T10:54:00+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/36M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Это не ошибка. Проект успешно собран и установлен в локальный репозиторий.

Comment: А где можно посмотреть, куда поставились нужные пакеты?

Comment: C:\Users\Tim\.m2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по представленным логам проект успешно собрался.

Путь к собранному jar файлу:

`C:\Users\Tim\eclipse-workspace\Project\target\Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
или `C:\Users\Tim\.m2\repository\com\tim\project\Project\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\Project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Оба варианта верны.